# how to print interface names only

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface

i want to print interface names only from `iwconfig` command
this is output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:&quot;CoreFragment&quot;  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 0C:D2:B5:55:DF:74   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:6567   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx00e02d01076f  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:&quot;Aleph_inCar&quot;  Nickname:&quot;&lt;WIFI@REALTEK&gt;&quot;
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:E0:2D:01:07:6F   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=4/100  Signal level=4/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx001e101f0000  no wireless extensions.
```

I tried this :

```
iwconfig | grep ESSID | sed 's/\"//g' | cut -f1  -d" "
```

but i got no wireless extension also in output
i want to get output from `iwconfig` command only
how print `wlp2s0,enp3s0,wlx00e02d01076f,enx001e101f0000` only...

Comment: yash did you try to pass the interface like `wlp2s0` to the ifconfig command?

Comment: yes..   I tried but i want to see my output from iwconfig @ValentinBajrami

Comment: then the easiest way would be `iwconfig 2>/dev/null | awk '/ESSID/{print $1}'`

Comment: Unclear: You say you don't want the interfaces with no wireless extension, but then you list these in the desired output.  What are you going to use the wireless interface names for?

Comment: Ok, so the question changed once again. Do you want `lo` also in the output? Why would you want `enp3s0` in the output. Why does it have to do with wireless interfaces?

Comment: i want enp3s0 not lo... i need enp3s0 for further process.. @ValentinBajrami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command works perfectly. Simply redirect the STDERR output to STDOUT, so that `grep` and `cut` process them as you want:

```
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep ESSID | sed 's/\"//g' | cut -f1  -d" "
```

However, this method using `grep`, `sed` and `cut` is an overkill. A single `grep` can get you what you want as suggested in the update below.

#### UDPATE:

As per the edited question, and given that the user is using Ubuntu (and hence the `grep` supports Perl regex), here is one method:

```
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep -oP "^\w+"
```

Comment: how I can remove lo from your suggested command :iwconfig 2>&1 | grep -oP "^\w+"

Comment: otherwise it works... @shivams

Comment: I think the use of `grep` , `sed` and `cut` is overkill for such a trivial task

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Yes. But the combination of the 3 was the one suggested by the OP. I have suggested an updated version.

Comment: @yashshah to remove `lo`, just add one more `grep` to the pipe: `iwconfig 2>&1 | grep -oP "^\w+" | grep -v lo`

Comment: @yashshah Perhaps this should do: `iwconfig 2>&1 | grep -v "no wireless" | grep -oP "^\w+"`. However, I think you should learn a bit about grep and regex.